Getting randomly PG::Error: can't open large object with rails application
I have a rails application using postgresql 16, i am using latest version 1.5.6 of pg gem.
I have the below method:-
  def file_length
    transaction do
      lo = active_connection.lo_open(self.oid, ::PG::INV_READ)
      size = active_connection.lo_lseek(lo, 0, 2)
      active_connection.lo_close(lo)
      size
    end
  end

I am getting randomly PG::Error: can't open large object error at line lo = active_connection.lo_open(self.oid, ::PG::INV_READ)
Please suggest how to fix it.
UPDATE:- in byebug
(byebug) self.oid
886548059

Here file downloads fine but randomly I get this error for the same file.

Maybe the large object doesn't exist?

I see you added a bounty but have you confirmed the large object actually exists for the given "oid"? The reason I ask is because the only time this error will be raised is if lo_open fails (i.e. returns -1) Source and the it appears the only reason this would fail is either: a) the Large Object does not exist; b) the SELECT permission is not available for the Large Object. lo_open

@engineersmnky updated question, let me know if I can provide anything more.
